# 3rd Normal Form violation?

Tags: normalization

I've got a photo review type of application, where the customer wants to have an option for the user to flag issues with the photos. So, for instance, a photo could be tagged as "fuzzy," "grainy," or "other." If "Other" is selected, a brief text description is required.

I am thinking I should create one table with all the issue types. Another table, will have foreign key relationships to the photo id, and the issue type id. I am thinking this table should also have a text type column for the "other" text if "other" is selected, otherwise that column will be null.

My dilemma, is, will this be a violation of normalization rules? If the "Other" text column is not null, then the assumption can be made that the issue type id will always be the one for "Other." So, that would be a transitive dependency, right? Any ideas on how to implement this without violating 3rd normal form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the column `OtherText` is `null`, you do not know the value of the column `IssueType`.  It could be fuzzy or grainy.  So `IssueType` is not dependent on `OtherText`.

Your design is not a 3NF violation.

Comment: But when the `IssueType` is anything (but "other") then the `OtherText` column is `null`. So it is a (partial) dependency.

Comment: Probably, but 3NF is not about partial dependencies :)

Comment: No, I agree on that. Depending on how one sees nullability, the table is either violating 1NF (having a nullable column) or (allowing nulls) it is ok with 1NF and 3NF - and only violates [DKNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain/key_normal_form).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry to much about the "Normal Forms".  They are excellent recommendations and should be followed where appropriate.  But only where appropriate.  In this particular case you don't have an issue with it anyway as @Andomar said, but I can think of several times when I have violated various normal forms in order to improve performance for queries or reporting.

Comment: In fact for reporting that is totally normal - not normalizing is standard for data warehouses.